# Why paginateChildRows property is not found for my ag-grid-angular component?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I used the default pagination mode (paginate only top rows) with my master detail grid. But it pushed child row to next page when I expand a parent row. Then I tried to set paginateChildRows = false, but I got the following error message:

Can't bind to 'paginateChildRows' since it isn't a known property of 'ag-grid-angular'

I did not use any of the following feature:

- Group Suppress Row
- Group Remove Single Children

So I am not forced to use the second pagination mode (pagination all rows).

This is definition for my ag-grid component:

```
<ag-grid-angular #agGridAll 
id="myGridAll"
style="height: 375px; border-radius:2px;"
class="ag-theme-balham" 
[rowData]="rowDataAll"
[columnDefs]="columnDefs" 
[defaultColDef] = "defaultColDef"  
(gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
[context]="context"
[frameworkComponents]="frameworkComponents"
[suppressClickEdit] = "true" 
[pagination] = "true"
[paginationPageSize]="paginationPageSize"
[masterDetail] = "true"
[detailCellRenderer] ="detailsCellRenderer"
[detailRowHeight]="detailRowHeight"
[editType]="editType"
[stopEditingWhenGridLosesFocus] = "true"
rowSelection="multiple" >
```

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? I'm on `20.1.0` and I don't see it, but it appears to be available on version 21.